# How to convert this SQL statement to ESQL

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a sql statement that updates multiple records at once. i would like to convert it to entity sql is possible.

```
UPDATE MyList SET Archived = True WHERE ID IN (1, 2, 3)
```

what is the ESQL equivalent of the above query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var idList = new List<int> { 1,2,3 };
dbContext.MyList.Where(x => idList.Contains(x.ID))
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(x => x.Archived = true);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```